# How can I add gap between bars of each series in React Apexcharts?

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

How can I add gap between bars of each `series` in [React Apexcharts](https://apexcharts.com/)?

[image: Edit react-apexcharts]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this config to `options`:

```
  stroke: {
    colors: ["transparent"],
    width: 5
  }
```

For more information, please refer to : [Related Document](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/stroke/)

[image: Edit react-apexcharts (forked)]